Tkinter window freezes when changing contents of HTMLLabel to a .html file

I am making a basic network with HTML files being sent from servers to clients and the HTML is successfully transferred as the HTML file is in the directory of the CLIENT.py code

However when I attempt to show this code on the tkinter window it freezes


import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkhtmlview import HTMLLabel
from WEBBROWSER import get_html


class SimpleBrowser:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title("Simple Browser")
        self.root.geometry("800x600")

        # Create the main frame
        self.main_frame = ttk.Frame(self.root, padding="10 10 10 10")
        self.main_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=(tk.N, tk.S, tk.E, tk.W))
        self.root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        # Create the search bar
        self.url_var = tk.StringVar()
        self.search_bar = ttk.Entry(self.main_frame, textvariable=self.url_var, width=60)
        self.search_bar.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=(tk.W, tk.E))
        self.search_button = ttk.Button(self.main_frame, text="Search", command=self.search_html)
        self.search_button.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)

        # Create the HTML viewer
        self.html_viewer = HTMLLabel(self.main_frame, html="<h1>Welcome to Simple Browser</h1>")
        self.html_viewer.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=(tk.N, tk.S, tk.E, tk.W))

        # Add row/column configuration
        self.main_frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.main_frame.columnconfigure(1, weight=0)
        self.main_frame.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)

    # GETTING AND SHOWING HTML =====================> ERROR IS PROBABLY HERE
    def search_html(self):
        url = self.search_bar.get()

        # Fetch HTML content and save it to a file
        get_html(url)

        # GET HTML FILE CONTENT
        html_file = open("WEBSITE.html", "r")
        html_file_cont = html_file.read()
        html_file.close()

        print(html_file_cont)

        # Display HTML file directly
        self.html_viewer.set_html(html_file_cont)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = SimpleBrowser(root)
    root.mainloop()

HTML FILE
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>TEST 1</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>HELLOW WORLD TEST1</h1>
</body>
</html>


I changed the code self.html_viewer.set_html(html_file_cont)  on the 5th last line to self.html_viewer.set_html("<h 1>CHANGED</h 1>") to see if the error came from displaying a HTML file in the first place but it still freezes


I added a space between H1 as stackoverflow was displaying changed as a header I didnt write it like that in my code

